# Sliding TabLayout Always in Center

Tags: android, android-tablayout, android-sliding

Hello first of all i'm a newbie for the libraries stuff.
I found a Demo Project on Github [here](https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout) but it contains more than i need

I want this like Slider
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUFCt.gif)

I have optimized it but its not working. So someone here, please take a look and guide me

Or any other stuff by which i can make that like layout?

Comment: Any codes? any layouts? any errors? there is always a demo or sample: https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout/tree/master/demo - especially: https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout/blob/master/demo/src/main/res/layout/demo_always_in_center.xml

Comment: I'd suggest that you use the official Android Support Library. Here is a tutorial http://blog.grafixartist.com/material-design-tabs-with-android-design-support-library/

Comment: @ShivPandey - Try this library https://github.com/jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip .

Easy to integrate.

Hope this will help you !!!

Comment: @LinX64 Demo is working fine but how do i distinguish the required one  ALWAYS IN CENTER.  The whole project contains many layouts and they are interconnected so i optimized them for my needs but it results in tons of errors.

Comment: Thanks @DannyBabbev it solved my two more problems :)

Answer (score 0):

Need to use padding for SlidingTabStrip. TabLayout has only `app:tabContatentStart` property, but you need to set both sides for this behavior.

Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36886331/651770