# How to programmatically change tabContentStart value in code?

Tags: android, android-tablayout, android-tabs

I have this scrollable TabLayout with tabContentStart set to 57dp offset in the XML.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabContentStart="57dp"
    app:tabMode="scrollable" />
```

What I want to do now is to change this value in the code in some if/else statement?

I couldn't find out how to achieve this. There doesn't seem to be an equivalent method for this in the TableLayout class.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41737107/7666442

Comment: that doesn't really do what I am looking for.

Comment: Have you did it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use setPadding or setTranslationX to get the desired effect.