# Selected tab scrolled to center

Tags: android, camera, tabs, android-viewpager, tabview

[image]

i want tabs like in image, when tab selected it scrolled to center, You may check you own device camera screen

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083638/android-center-align-the-selected-tab-in-tablayout